# Telling if a class adheres to a certain protocol in Swift

Tags: swift, protocols

I have two classes and a protocol, one looks like this:

```
protocol House{
    //vars and stuff here
}

class Thing: House{
    //more stuff here
}

class otherThing {
    //stuff here as well
}
```

I want a way to check that Thing adheres to protocol House, and also tell that otherThing does not.  I have tried to use the "is" operator but keep getting a warning that it always returns true.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check that a *type* conforms to a protocol, you shouldn't do that through its instances. A correct implementation of what you asked for is

```
let t: AnyClass = Thing.self
if t is House.Type {
    print("foo") // prints
}
let o: AnyClass = otherThing.self
if o is House.Type {
    print("bar") // doesn't print
}
```